# How to get a screenshot of only main screen using key combination?

Tags: windows, screenshot

Currently, to capture quickly a lot of screen, I use Ctrl+PrintScreen keys.

On Windows 10, this solution works well and quickly.

A PNG file is directly copied in `C:\Users\<%userid%>\Pictures\Screenshots` folder.

The problem is that I have **2** screens and when I press Ctrl+PrintScreen keys  an image that contains a screenshot of both screens is genarated !

Is there a key's combinations that allow to capture only active screen ?

Answer (score 1):

Move your mouse to the monitor you want to screenshot, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScrn</kbd>. Then just paste the screenshot into an image editor such as paint, paint.NET, etc and save.

Comment: Yes, this work but for any image, I must save it using an image editor. It is very painful and don't answer to my question. Thanks for the effort.